# permissions installing yeoman with npm - eaccess?

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I installed npm with homebrew and had to link it - i'm thinking this may be some part of the issue. This is all new to me so I am seeking any help. I am trying to install yeoman and some other things on a computer with

```
npm install -g yo
```

however it is spitting back the error -

```
   npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
 npm ERR! node v0.12.0
 npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
 npm ERR! path /Users/Lynda/npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib
 npm ERR! code EACCES
 npm ERR! errno -13 

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Lynda/npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Lynda/npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Lynda/npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Lynda/npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Lynda/npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/Lynda/npm-global/lib/node_modules/yo/lib' }
```

I did a bunch of googling and can't find anything, could use some help! I'd like to avoid sudo'ing if I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred way of installing node & npm on OSX:

Install node via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) without `npm`:

```
brew update
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.node >> ~/.npmrc
```

Then install `npm` via the install script on [npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.org):

If you're wild and crazy:

```
curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Otherwise, download https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh, inspect to your satisfaction, chmod +x and execute it.

Then add `$HOME/.node/bin` to your path.

Note: If you've previuously installed node + npm via the graphical installer or homebrew, you'll want to remove the previous install before installing again. For instance, if you installed via the graphical installer:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
rm -rf /usr/local/include/node
rm -rf ~/.npm
mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc-old
```

Answer (score 2):

you can own the directory that npm is trying to install to, I too disliked having to `sudo`. In fact, NPM [states that you shouldn't sudo as well](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

try:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /Users/Lynda/npm-global/lib/node_modules
```

remember that this will bind it to your current user, `whoami` is a bash variable to get your user name.

Comment: It's the `node_modules` path, not `npm`.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to avoid sudo'ing, I recommend you use a version manager for node such as [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). This allows to install global packages without sudo and also to run different versions of node and/or io.js side by side.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this:

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Then sudo is probably exactly what you need to use. Try `sudo npm install -g yo`

Answer (score 0):

As this line

`npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator`

states, you need to have admin credentials to install the yeoman. So you can try with `sudo npm install -g yo`