# npm not installing even after installing node

Tags: node.js, git, npm, homebrew

I'm setting up a new project to work on and the goal is to install Grunt and Bower. Now Both of them require to have installed the latest npm & Node.js versions. As I was installing it I faced a few problem with git that was able to fix. Where I'm stuck now, is that after installing everything as listed in all the online guides apparently npm is not there...? the npm site mentions that this would be installed with Node.js and still after installing, looks like npm is not there....

**here is what I got:**

```
user-mbp:~ username$ git --version
git version 2.1.3.36.g8e36a6d

user-mbp:~ username$ node -v
v0.12.2

user-mbp:~ username$ brew -v
Homebrew 0.9.5

user-mbp:~ username$ sass -v
Sass 3.4.13 (Selective Steve)

user-mbp:~ username$ npm -v
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like OSX? How did you install node?

Comment: Try installing nodejs as sudo user

Comment: BTW, [this is my (current) preferred way to install node and npm on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733551/permissions-installing-yeoman-with-npm-eaccess/28734540#28734540)

Comment: @steveeax I'm installing on OSX. The way node was installed, was from the node-v0.12.2.pkg package downloaded from nodejs.org site.

Comment: @Sathish did try the sudo command but still didn't work. Do you think if I uninstall everything and re-install node.js will fix this? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @steveax did try your link. and npm didn't install :(

Answer (score 0):

uninstall everything and re-installing node.js did fix this. Not sure why it didn't work the first time.